# Can I put a layout inside a QuickAction?

Tags: android, android-layout, quickaction

The layout contains my google map represented by a variable viewmap.
I want that in a QuickAction should contain a map. In such a way, when I click on a list of places or country it will pop up a map on top of the ListItem.
For example:

when I click philippines it will display a map over on the list.

Comment: What programming framework are you asking about?

Comment: android. I am developing map application. Basically, the following are included: an ActionBar, MapView. There are three classes involved, the MainActivity, ListActivity, Maps extends MapActivity.

Comment: You should include that sort of information in the question.  People can't answer if they don't know what you're talking about.  You should also mention what you've tried and what problems you've encountered.

Comment: ok.thank you sir. I think I'm now closer to what I want. I did some research and by combining those two resources I've got, I think it will be done.Anyways, I'll post the code later on if I already done with it.

Comment: @user1599854 ifr you achieved this thing please post the code that how to include the layout in quickaction